# what is `public: true` in okteto-stack.yml?

Tags: docker-compose, okteto

While reading this article on Okteto (https://www.okteto.com/blog/deploying-a-django-app-on-okteto/), there was a configuration for `public: true`.

```yaml
  simple-rbas:
    public: true
      image:okteto.dev/simple-rbas:latest
    build: .
    # ...
```

what does turning this on affect? will it mean that this image will be publicly avaible for everyone else to pull?

I have checked the documents on Okteto & Docker Compose, but I was not able to find a reference for this setting.

My app is aimed only for members on my team to access, and since I have not done a thorough security check, I would like to keep my apps/code as private as possibly, while opening a public URL so I can share my app via a link.

I would like to know how `public: true` will affect my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax was used in the past to mark if a port should be publicly available. That was deprecated earlier this year in favor of having a syntax close to docker-compose.

For this particular case, you should define port 8000 as below to tell Okteto that you want it to be available from the internet.

```
ports:
  - 8000:8000
```

https://www.okteto.com/docs/reference/compose/#ports-int-optional has more information on how to make a port publicly available.